# How to create a data mining model in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, machine-learning, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to create a data mining model using Oracle SQL developer. However, it is not working. I've checked the Oracle docs before posting here but I couldn't resolve this.

I'm trying the code below:

```
    -- Create the settings table for DT
    CREATE TABLE decision_tree_model_settings (
    setting_name VARCHAR2(30),
    setting_value VARCHAR2(30));

    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO decision_tree_model_settings (setting_name, setting_value)
    VALUES (dbms_data_mining.algo_name,dbms_data_mining.algo_decision_tree); 

    INSERT INTO decision_tree_model_settings (setting_name, setting_value)
    VALUES (dbms_data_mining.prep_auto,dbms_data_mining.prep_auto_on); 
    COMMIT;
    END; 
    /

   -- CREATE MODEL
   -- Create the model using the specified settings 
   BEGIN
   DBMS_DATA_MINING.CREATE_MODEL(
   model_name          => 'Decision_Tree_Model',
   mining_function     => dbms_data_mining.classification,
   data_table_name     => 'TRAIN_SET',
   target_column_name  => 'Y',
   settings_table_name => 'decision_tree_model_settings');
   END;
   /
```

The code to create the model is returning the error below:

```
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CREATE_MODEL'
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Thank you,

Eduardo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the fourth *obligatory* `CREATE_MODEL`'s parameter: `CASE_ID_COLUMN_NAME`.

This is the procedure's description:

```
DBMS_DATA_MINING.CREATE_MODEL (
      model_name            IN VARCHAR2,               --> you have it
      mining_function       IN VARCHAR2,               --> you have it
      data_table_name       IN VARCHAR2,               --> you have it
      case_id_column_name   IN VARCHAR2,               --> YOU DO NOT HAVE IT!
      target_column_name    IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
      settings_table_name   IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
      data_schema_name      IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
      settings_schema_name  IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
      xform_list            IN TRANSFORM_LIST DEFAULT NULL);
```

Parameters whose default values are `NULL` aren't obligatory, but you **MUST** provide all parameters that are required (i.e. the first 4 of them - no exceptions).

Once you include it, you should be OK. I can't try it myself as 11g XE doesn't have the mining option enabled.

Comment: I THINK it's included in 18c XE